# Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm in $\Bbb{R}.$ Show that $(\Bbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ and $(\Bbb{R}, \|\cdot\|)$ are bilipschitz-equivalent.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm in $\Bbb{R}.$ Show that $(\Bbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ and $(\Bbb{R}, \|\cdot\|)$ are bilipschitz-equivalent.

In order to show this I have to find $M$ such that $$\frac1M|x-y|\leqslant\|x-y\|\leqslant M|x-y|$$

However I'm not sure how to proceed here? The question seemed easy, but I cannot find where to start?

Comment: We have $$ \Vert x \Vert = \Vert x \cdot 1\Vert = \vert x\vert \cdot \Vert 1 \Vert.$$

Comment: Where does the equality $\|x \cdot 1 \| = |x| \cdot \|1\|$ come from?

Comment: @DanielLi The positive scalar homogeneity property of $\| \cdot \|$; treat $x$ as the scalar, and $1$ as the vector.